# Как обработать возможный выход за границу массива и продолжить выполнение программы, избежав ошибки

Tags: c#

Решаю учебную задачу, нужно написать код для обработки изображения с камеры для робота-пылесоса, которого пнула хозяйка, и теперь ему нужно сориентироваться в пространстве))

В данный момент пишу код для медианного фильтра. Суть в том, что нужно для каждого пикселя в изображении (которое представлено в виде двумерного массива) взять его окрестные пиксели, поместить в массив, отсортировать этот массив, а затем вернуть средний элемент этого массива - это и будет итоговый цвет обрабатываетмого пикселя.
Как нетрудно догадаться, для пикселей в центре изображения количество окрестных пикселей будет 8, для пикселей по периметру 5, а для угловых пикселей - 3, и это нужно как-то обработать.

Я хочу решить эту задачу, избежав использования целой кучи if-ов для проверок на то, не является ли обрабатываемый пиксель крайним или угловым. Пока что, так как пикселей в середине изображения намного больше, чем по периметру, я решил обработать сначала их - это можно сделать без if-ов вообще. Но вот с пикселями по периметру вышел затык. Как ни крути, а проверка для них понадобится... Или же нет?

Если бы можно было создать метод или локальную функцию, которая бы принимала индекс обрабатываемого пикселя и пробовала запросить для него значения соседних пикселей, а в случае неудачи (ввиду того, что пикселя не существует) просто продалжала работу с теми пикселями, значения которых удастся получить, то это было былучшим решением данной задачи, как мне кажется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, такой вариант возможен?

Comment: Обработка исключений медленнее, чем проверки `if`-ами. Но если у вас в скорость работы ничего не упирается, то можете и так сделать, главное не перепутать, где желаемое вами исключение, а где реально что-то ещё пошло не так.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только Вы не написалали, как - так? Вы это про идею с try-catch? Скорость в общем не важна, задача учебная. Но хочется, конечно, сделать эффективно. Учебные задачи для обучения существуют, всё таки, и нужно извлекать из них максимум

Comment: Да, я имел в виду через try/catch. Но так то это не такая задача, где это реально требуется. Тут нужно просто нормально посчитать границы.

Comment: А почему try-catch медленнее? If-ы проверяют условия, а блок try просто выполняет то что внутри без проверок, и только при ошибке переключается на catch... Вроде наоборот быстрее должны быть

Comment: Ну, так устроена среда исполнения. `if`-ы выполняются буквально в один такт процессора, если там нужно сравнивать целые числа. А try/catch требует хитрой обвязки, чтобы ловить исключения.

Comment: Понял, благодарю! Буду знать. А возможно ли ловить конкретное исключение с помощью if-а? По идее выход за граница массива - это одно и то же исключение каждый раз, когда оно будет происходить. Как по мне, то настройка программы на игнорирование Одного Конкретного исключения в Одном Конкретном случае - вполне нормальное, и в чём-то даже изящное решение. Ибо обход массива осуществляется самой программой и не зависит от внешних данных, т.е. действий пользователя, а значит это моё дело, как обрабатывать нештатную ситуацию... Вроде разумно...)

Comment: Сейчас, обдумывая эту задачку под кофеёк пришла в голову ещё одна идея) Можно перекинуть обрабатываемое изображение в массив большего размера (т.е. +2 пикселя для каждого измерения), заполненного некоторыми значениями для явной идентификации пустых ячеек (например, -1) и поместить изображение в центр этого массива. Тогда ошибка с выходом за границу массива исчезнет, и нужна будет всего одна проверка - на положительное значение. Только вот как это осуществить... Как бы не оказалось сложнее, чем обложить всё if-ами...)

Comment: Просто забейте на полоску в 1 пиксель по периметру и никакие индексы проверять не нужно будет

Comment: Если бы я решал такую задачу на практике (с реальной целью), то я бы так и сделал. Но задача учебная, и такое решение во-первых не примут, а во-вторых цель учебных заданий - научиться. Не столько писать программы для управления роботами-пылесосами, сколько развить гибкость мышления и воображение именно применительно к коду. Так что надо доделать)

Answer (score 0):

Так сделайте функцию, которая возвращает список индексов соседей. А потом этот список и обрабатывайте. Условные операторы всё равно придётся использовать, но уже в отдельной функции, которая формирует список индексов соседей. Так будет проще управлять кодом.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Жаль, хотелось как-то без if-ов обойтись...

Comment: Обдумывал Ваш ответ и появилась мысль - сделать в функции для запроса индексов блоки try..catch внутри цикла. Блок try будет пытаться запросить значение пикселя, а при возникновении ошибки блок catch сменит индекс и цикл продолжится. А дальше можно будет работать с теми значениями, которые удастся получить. Как Вам такой вариант? Коряво?)

Comment: Главное, чтобы была включена проверка на индексы. В некоторых случаях при компиляции окончательного релиза эту проверку отключают. Хотя, есть возможность  с помощью директив её включить для определённого участка кода.

Comment: Не понял, где и зачем нужна проверка на индексы? В блоке try? А смысл? Индексы мне вроде как не нужны, нужно просто получить значение соседних пикселей и вычислить из них медиану, т.е. фактически мне нужно просто получить значение этого самого среднего пикселя. Поэтому думал просто засунуть try-catch в цикл и пускай себе ищет всё что сможет...

Comment: Чтобы вызвать исключение, которое будет перехвачено в try. Иначе просто будет неправильная работа с памятью.

Comment: Океееей... Понял. Спасибо за замечание, запомню это.

Answer (score 0):

Обрабатываете область c индексами от 1 до width-2 и аналогично по высоте   - проверки не нужны
Обрабатываете две строки горизонтальных пикселов от 1 до width-2, учитывая 5 соседей - проверки не нужны
Обрабатываете две колонки вертикальных пикселов от 1 до height-2, учитывая 5 соседей  - проверки не нужны
Обрабатываете 4 угла, учитывая трех соседей

---

Если однообразно хочется, то (будет чуть помедленнее)

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++ {
    //обработка области с центром в (y,x)
        int count = 0;
        for (int dy = max(0,y-size); dy <= min(y+size, height-1); dy++) {
           for (int dx = max(0,x-size); dx <= min(x+size, width-1); dx++) {
              Med[count++] = A[dy][dx];
           }
        }
        Array.Sort(Med, 0, count-1);
        MedianArr[y][x] = Med[count/2];
    }
 }
```

Однако прямая реализация принципа медианной фильтрации не быстро работает. Если нужна скорость, то воспользуйтесь, например, библиотекой OpenCV

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Только Вы немного не поняли вопрос. У меня нет проблемы с обходом массива пикселей, есть проблема с получением для каждого из них значений окрестных пикселей. Ну например, мы обрабатываем угловой пиксель под индексом [0, 0]. Для вычисления медианы нам нужны значения пикселей под индексами [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]. Если делать это с помощью шаблона для пикселей в центре, рассчитанного на 8 окрестных пикселей, то возникнет исключение. И я ищу изящный способ, как решить эту задачу, не создавая гору if-ов

Comment: Я понял вопрос. Расширил описание второго способа

Comment: Хорошо, возможно я недостаточно вник. Сейчас обдумаю...

Comment: Если я  правильно понял Вашу идею (псевдокод пока плохо понимаю), то Вы предлагаете организовать проверку на нахождение индекса в границах массива не с помощью if-ов, а с помощью методов Math.Max и Math.Min, верно? Если так, то мне не совсем ясно, как будет искаться медиана при таком подходе. Если только записывать куда-то номера найденных ячеек, удалять дублирование (которое будет возникать при обращении к несуществующим ячейкам, ведь Max и Min будут возвращать значения), и потом использовать эти индексы для доступа уже только к нужным ячейкам. Я верно понял Вашу мысль?

Comment: А как вы сейчас делаете? Номера никуда записывать не надо. Если вы работаете с массивом в 9 ячеек для вычисления медианы, сразу записывайте A[dy][dx]  в  Med[count++], потому сортируйте count ячеек массива MEd и берите Med[count/2]

Comment: Так и делаю, это есть в описании. Для массива из 9 ячеек. Но если мы работаем например с угловым пикселем [0, 0], то у нас должен получиться массив из 4 ячеек, а по Вашему варианту (если я верно его понял, опять же) у нас всё равно получится массив из 9 ячеек с дублированием, потому что метод Max при попытке запросить значение несуществующих ячеек (т.е. индексы -1) будет возвращать значения крайних ячеек (индекс 0, т.к. 0 больше -1), и сделает это несколько раз (один раз при обращении непосредственно к крайней ячейке, и один раз при обращении к ячейке за крайней).

Comment: Вы бы хоть попробовали и посмотрели на count

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я очень смутно понимаю Ваш код, а потому не могу его попробовать. И задаю вопросы именно чтобы разобраться. Пойму идею - пойму как попробовать

Comment: Что ж вам, скобок не хватает? Вот, близко к C#.

Comment: Я Вам про логику, а Вы про скобки... Я думал что Вы предлагали запрашивать содержимое ячеек явно указывая их индексы. Сказали бы что Max и Min - это для получения переменных цикла, и вопросы бы сразу отпали. Вопросов нет, спасибо за идею!

Answer (score 0):

Особые случаи - угловые и линейные - обрабатывай отдельно от остальных.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.